# Is there any member function defined with std::array in c++20?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, member, c++20

As I realized so far, there are no members like(sort, accumulate,push_back .. ) with a standard array, right? I think all of these nice methods only work with vector

Comment: `vector` doesn't have sort or accumulate either. Those are *algorithms* which work on any range (restricted to the iterator types they take, of course).

Comment: @NicolBolas so having said that, these methods (sort, accumulate) also should work with array. What about any performance difference when using array instead of vector?

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) you can find the member functions of `std::array` (which, beeing a "a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays" would have no use of a push_back, BTW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many member functions in std::array, like begin, end, rbegin, rend, max_size, fill etc, like it is mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/)

Comment: Prefer cppreference, and put the answer in your answer. The link should be a supplement, not the whole thiing.